# Alternative to stream for converting Charsequence to String

Tags: java, android, string, charsequence

I'm writing a mobile application in Android studio. 
I have an arrayList that i'm converting into a string to be evaluated in a script engine.

I am currently using

```
    resultText = total.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(""));
```

With total being

```
    ArrayList<CharSequence> total = new ArrayList<>();
```

The current input output is something like this

```
    CharSequence [1,+,2] --> .Stream() "1+2" --> .eval 3.0
```

Is there an alternative method to get this output? I'm currently using API level 28 to have access to stream, but i require a min API level of 19.

The .ToString() method does not get the required output.

```
    CharSequence [1,+,2] --> .ToString "[1,+,2]" --> .eval NULL
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are you talking about `java.lang.CharSequence` then `total.toString()` will do what you want.

Comment: You say you are converting an `ArrayList` to a `String` in the first paragraph, and then you say `total` is a `CharSequence`. So, which is it – an `ArrayList` or a `CharSequence`?

Comment: total is an ArrayList<CharSequence>. Ill update the question to make it more clear. 
total.ToString preserves the square brackets and the commas within the ArrayLists structure and will fail to be evaluated by the ScriptEngine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TextUtils` class.

```
List<Character> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
        '1', '+', '2'
));

String result = TextUtils.join("", list);
```

Base od [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils#join(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.Iterable)) method `join()` was `Added in API level 1`

Comment: This exact same functionality is available as `String.join()` in Java 8.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following :

```
resultText = total.toString(); // where total is CharSequence Array.
```

your eval function should work with this.

Comment: What do you mean by "CharSequence Array"? Isn't it just a CharSequence?